# Qt cross platform safe way of storing data in an SQLite database?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out the safest way of storing chat history for my application on the clients computer. By "safe" I mean so that my application is allowed to actually read/write to the `SQLite database`. Clients will range from Windows, OS X and Linux users. So i need to find a way on each platform of determining where I'm allowed to create a `SQLite database` for storing the message history.

Problems I've run into in the past were for example when people used terminal clients for example `Citrix` where the users is not allowed to write to almost any directory. The drive is often a shared network drive.

Some ideas:

1. Include an empty database.db within my installer that contains prebuilt tables. And store the database next to my executable. However I'm almost certain that not all clients will be allowed to read/write here, for example Windows users who do not have admin rights.
2. Use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation` and create the database at the first run time
3. Locate the `users home dir` and create the database at the first run time

Any ideas if there is a really good solution to this problem?

Comment: `QSettings` seems to have a way to determine a writable location if used in XML mode. Maybe check how it's done there.

Comment: I would  do #2 or #3. Both are reasonable solutions that should work on linux, osx or windows.